# How to await the creation of a document created in cloud functions with onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to securely create a `user` document `onCreate` that is in sync with the `auth.user` database in Firebase v9.
I think it wouldn't be secure to let a registered user create a user document. So I wrote a cloud function which triggers on `functions.auth.user().onCreate()` and creates a user document.

**Problem:**

I have the problem keeping them in sync as the `onSnapshot`method which should await for the user document to exists already returns a promise if the user document does not yet exists. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. So I don't know when I can update the by the cloud function created `user` document.

**Question:**

Why does the onSnapshot sometimes work and sometimes not. How can I fix it?

Here is a link to a helpful Article which seem to doesn't work in v9. [Link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07)

I tried and searched everywhere. I can't believe this is not a standard feature and still a requested topic. This seems so basic.

#### Error

`error FirebaseError: No document to update:` as `const user = await createAccount(displayName, email, password);` returns even if user is not yet in doc.data()

#### Sign Up function

```js
interface SignUpFormValues {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    confirm: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }

const createAccount = async (
    displayName: string,
    email: string,
    password: string
  ) => {
    // Create auth user
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    // -> Signed in

    // Update Profile
    const user = userCredential.user;
    const uid = user.uid;
    await updateProfile(user, {
      displayName: displayName,
    });

    // IMPORTANT: Force refresh regardless of token expiration
    // auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true); // -> will stop the onSnapshot function from resolving properly

    // Build a reference to their per-user document
    const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", uid);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(userDocRef, {
        next: (doc) => {
          unsubscribe();
          console.log("doc", doc); // -> returning undefined
          console.log("doc.data()", doc.data()); // -> returning undefined
          resolve(user); // -> returning undefined
        },
        error: (error) => {
          unsubscribe();
          console.log("error", error);
          reject(error);
        },
      });
    });
  };

const handleSignUp = async (values: SignUpFormValues) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = values;
    const displayName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

    try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);

      // Create user account
      const user = await createAccount(displayName, email, password);
      console.log("createAccount -> return:", user); // -> problem here sometimes return undefined

      // Update user
      const newUserData = {
        displayName: displayName,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      };
      // Build a reference to their per-user document
      const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      await updateDoc(userDocRef, newUserData);

      // Send Email verification
      await authSendEmailVerification(user);

      // Logout
      await logout();

      navigate("/sign-up/email-verification", { state: values });
    } catch (error: any) {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error", error);
      console.log("error", errorCode);
      if (errorCode === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        const errorMessage =
          "Failed to create an account. E-Mail address is already registered.";
        setError(errorMessage);
        console.log("error", errorMessage);
      } else {
        setError("Failed to create account.");
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

#### Cloud function which triggers the user onCreate

```js
// On auth user create
export const authUserWriteListener = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate(async (user, context) => {
    console.log("user:", user);
    const userRef = db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    await userRef.set({
      email: user.email,
      createdAt: context.timestamp,
      firstTimeLogin: true,
    });

    return db.doc("stats/users").update({
      totalDocsCount: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the Cloud Function code runs asynchronously.  There is no guarantee that it will run quickly enough to have the document created in Firestore between the end of `createAccount()` and your call to `updateDoc()`.  In fact, if your system has been idle for a while it could be a minute (or more!) for the Cloud Function to execute (do [a search for "cold start firebase cloud functions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cold%20start%20firebase%20cloud%20functions)).

One option, depending on your design, might be to not take in first name and last name during sign up?  But instead take the user to a "profile page" once they are logged in where they could modify aspects of their profile (by that time the user profile document hopefully is created).  On that page, if the `get()` returns no document, you could put up a notification to the user that the system "is still processing their registration" or something like that.

Comment: I know that cloud function code runs asynchronously but still as referenced in the question link it should work stated by multiple people who are working with firebase for years. [link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07) . To your async/await tip, I didn't use then() in my code, what exactly do you mean? What would you change?

Comment: Bad choice of wording on my part.  I have removed.  But I don't see value of `new Promise()` in an async function.  Why not simply call the function directly, with try/catch if you want to handle any exceptions?

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to accomplish with the Promise....I have little faith it will do what you are hoping it to, but I could be wrong.  Have you considered instead setting a state variable then using `useEffect(..., [fetchProfileFlag])` to start the onSnapshot() ?